# averaging text document with string in python

Tags: python

I need to make a table that pulls one or more person's name and scores at various games from a text file, then find the average, minimum and maximum of each person's scores and display them.

EDIT-here is my current code:

```
    while name!='':
    floor=text_file.readline().rstrip()
    rings=text_file.readline().rstrip()
    p_bars=text_file.readline().rstrip()
    p_horse=text_file.readline().rstrip()
    h_bar=text_file.readline().rstrip()


    floor_int=int(floor)
    rings_int=int(rings)
    p_bars_int=int(p_bars)
    p_horse_int=int(p_horse)
    h_bar_int=int(h_bar)

    score_sum=floor_int+rings_int+p_bars_int+p_horse_int+h_bar_int
    avg=score_sum/5
```

how would I be able to do math with the lines that have numbers and exclude the lines that have names?

EDIT: running that code gives me this:
        TypeError: Can't convert 'float' object to str implicitly

any ideas?

Comment: You know, you could just do `floor = text_file.readline().rstrip()`, for example. (And you don't need to specify "\n" as `rstrip()` defaults to removing all whitespace).

Comment: fyi, `if name != '':` is very unpythonic. Simply use `if name:`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming 'rings' is a line that has a number, you can add all those by creating int or float objects, for example:

```
rings=rings.rstrip('\n')
rings_int = int(rings)
sum_of_rings += rings_int
```

If there is a mix of numbers and other text within a line, use a regular expression to pull out the number part first:

```
import re

m = re.search('\d+', rings)
if m:
    rings_int_str = m.group()
    rings_int = int( rings_int_str )
    sum_of_rings += rings_int
```

I use a lot of individual variables to clarify this, but the steps can be combined, for example:

```
sum_of_rings += int( text_file.readline() )
```

P.S. If you are getting that error, it is probably in a print statement where you are trying to print avg without converting it to a string somehow.  Either of these works:

```
avg=score_sum/5.0
print "%f" % (avg)
print str(avg)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your numbers are decimal numbers, you can do this :

```
if line.isdigit():
    my_number = int(line)
```

Comment: @alex edited with current code, if you gentlemen would care to have a look.